# Detect mock location in Oreo

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-gps, google-location-services

I am using

```
@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location.isFromMockProvider())
    {}
 }
```

but `location.isFromMockProvider()` returns always `false`.

Fake GPS apps that I am using: Fake GPS and Fake GPS Pro

I have also used this sample https://github.com/klaasnotfound/LocationAssistant but none of them worked properly.

Comment: did you set the Location Mode to GPS only in phone settings?

Comment: No I use location method High accuracy

Comment: you should use GPS only for mock location

Comment: @FisnikIbishi Did you find any work around?